# Building an App with Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, frameworks, python-3.x, tkinter

So, I've run into a bit of snag concerning building a basic GUI app with Python. I can concern with the details of the app, if needed, but the basic problem lies within getting this error:

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
       self.entryVariable.set(u"Enter text here.")

I've been following a tutorial on how to build a GUI in Python, but it's written with release 2.7 in mind (not 3.3, which I'm using). Here's the code:

```
import tkinter
  class simpleapp_tk(tkinter.Tk):
        def __init__(self,parent):
            tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, parent)
            self.parent = parent
            self.initialize()
        #----------------------------
        def initialize(self):
            self.grid()
            #
            self.entryVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
            self.entry = tkinter.Entry(self, textvariable=self.entryVariable)
            self.entry.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='EW')
            self.entry.bind("<Return>", self.OnPressEnter
            self.entryVariable.set(u"Enter text here.")
            #The code goes on............
```

So any ideas what's going wrong? I can provide the rest of the code if needed.

Comment: For what it's worth, the statement `self.grid()` at the start of `initialize` does absolutely nothing and should be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing a closing bracket on the line before the error:
self.entry.bind("", self.OnPressEnter

Comment: Happens to everyone. That's where this site comes into action :)

Answer (score 0):

seems you left a comma after u in `self.entryVariable.set(u"Enter text here.")`

Try running after giving a comma after u, if still it gives error.. it will be better if you share whole code, so that i can myself try to run the code & short out the error.